# SwiftUI Z-Stack Item appears to be removed from under original Item

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a tinder like swiping mechanic in my app that lets the user swipe cards to the left and right or use buttons that should do the swiping action. For the swiping itself it works perfectly fine, but when using the buttons to swipe the cards it appears that the cards gets removed one layer below in the Z-Stack and not from the top like it is when swiping it with your finger.

This is my swipe able Card:

```
@EnvironmentObject var buttonState: ButtonState
@State var offset: CGFloat = 0
@GestureState var isDragging: Bool = false
@State var endSwipe: Bool = false
@State var buttonPressed = false

GeometryReader { proxy in
            let size = proxy.size
            let index = CGFloat(cardVM.getIndex(card: card))
Card()
.frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                                .offset(x: offset)
                                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: getRotation(angle: 8)))
                                .contentShape(Rectangle().trim(from: 0, to: endSwipe ? 0 : 1))
                                .gesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .updating($isDragging, body: { value, out, _ in
                                            out = true
                                        })
                                        .onChanged({ value in
                                            let translation = value.translation.width
                                            offset = (isDragging ? translation : .zero)
                                            self.swipeRight = translation > 0 ? true : false
                                            
                                            buttonState.right = translation > 0 ? true : false
                                            buttonState.isDragging = true
                                        })
                                        .onEnded({ value in
                                            let width = getRect().width - 50
                                            let translation = value.translation.width
                                            let checkingStatus = (translation > 0 ? translation : -translation)
                                            buttonState.isDragging = false
                                            
                                            withAnimation {
                                                if checkingStatus > (width / 2) {
                                                    
                                                    offset = (translation > 0 ? width : -width) * 2
                                                    endSwipe = true
                                                    translation > 0 ? rightSwipe() : leftSwipe()
                                                    endSwipeActions()
                                                } else {
                                                    offset = .zero
                                                }
                                            }
                                        })
                                )
                                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name("ACTIONFROMBUTTON"), object: nil)) { data in
                                    guard let info = data.userInfo else {
                                        return
                                    }
                                    
                                    let id = info["id"] as? String ?? ""
                                    let rightSwipe = info["rightSwipe"] as? Bool ?? false
                                    let width = getRect().width - 50
                                    
                                    if card.id == id {
                                        withAnimation {
                                            offset = (rightSwipe ? width : -width) * 2
                                            endSwipeActions()
                                            
                                            if rightSwipe {
                                                self.rightSwipe()
                                            } else {
                                                leftSwipe()
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
}
```

```
class ButtonState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var right = false
    @Published var isDragging = false
}
```

This is what I do for a right swipe in my main View:

```
func doSwipe(rightSwipe: Bool = false) {
        guard let first = cardVM.displayingCards?.first else {
            return
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("ACTIONFROMBUTTON"), object: nil, userInfo: [
            "id": first.id,
            "rightSwipe": rightSwipe
        ])
    }

Button("Swipe right") {
buttonState.isDragging = true
buttonState.right = true
doSwipe(rightSwipe: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have look at this code I have that works perfectly for swiping the the profiles like tinder application. Replace the dummy data with your actual data.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwipCard: View {

    let geometry: GeometryProxy
    @State private var cards = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    @State private var x: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    @State private var degree: [Double] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

    @State private var likeOpcity = 0.0
    @State private var disLikeOpcity = 0.0

    var body: some View {

            ZStack {
                Color.black.opacity(0.05).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                ZStack {

                    ForEach(cards.indices, id: \.self) { index in

                        ZStack {
                            // get the heigt of screen and set it accordig to the screen

                            Image(String(Int(index) + 1))
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 20, height: geometry.size.height - 53)
                                    .clipped()

                            userInfoView()
                        }
                        .offset(x: x[index])
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(degree[index]))
                            .transition(.scale(scale: 0.1, anchor: .center))
                            .gesture(DragGesture()
                                .onChanged({ value in

                                    if value.translation.width > 15 {
                                        // if image is draging at righ side
                                        x[index] = value.translation.width
                                        self.degree[index] = 8
                                        // change the opcity of like image
                                        likeOpcity = Double(value.translation.width / 100)

                                    } else if value.translation.width < -15 {
                                        // if image is dragin at left side
                                        x[index] = value.translation.width
                                        self.degree[index] = -8
                                        // change the opcity of dislike view
                                        disLikeOpcity =  Double(abs(value.translation.width / 100))
                                    }

                                })
                                .onEnded({ value in
                                    withAnimation {

                                        if value.translation.width > 0 {
                                            likeOpcity = 0
                                            // when drage is at right side
                                            if value.translation.width > 100 {
                                                self.x[index] = 500
                                                self.degree[index] = 15
                                            } else {
                                                self.x[index] = 0
                                                self.degree[index] = 0

                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            disLikeOpcity = 0
                                            // when drage is at left
                                            if value.translation.width < -100 {
                                                self.x[index] = -500
                                                self.degree[index] = -15
                                            } else {
                                                self.x[index] = 0
                                                self.degree[index] = 0
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                })
                            )

                    }

                    HStack {

                        Image(ImageName.dislike.rawValue)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .opacity(disLikeOpcity)
                        Spacer()

                        Image(ImageName.like.rawValue)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .opacity(likeOpcity)

                    }

                }

            }

    }
}

// MARK: View Extensino
extension SwipCard {

    func userInfoView() -> some View {

        VStack {
            Spacer()

            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {

                    HStack {

                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Text("Samantha")
                            Text("22")
                        }.font(.custom(Popins.bold.rawValue, size: 20))

                        Image(ImageName.crown.rawValue)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    }

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("lahore")
                        Text("MIT USA")
                        Text("Software Developer")
                    }.font(.custom(Popins.regular.rawValue, size: 14))

                }.foregroundColor(.white)

                Spacer()

                // Button stack
                VStack {
                    BlueButton(action: {
                        Helper.shared.printDebug("student")
                    }, title: "Studnet")
                    .frame(width: 110, height: 30)
                    .clipped()
                    .cornerRadius(5).disabled(true)

                    BlueButton(action: {
                        Helper.shared.printDebug("student")
                    }, title: "Chat")
                    .frame(width: 110, height: 30)
                    .clipped()
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                }

            }

        }.padding()

    }

}
```

You just need to pass the geometry object to SwipView to make its size matched with the current Screen size. Call this View from any parent view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            SwipCard(geometry: geometry)
        }
    }
}
```